# How to combine unique values into count function

Tags: oracle

I have a report that I am trying to write for members that counts the total number of unique values for each type on one line.  Here is what I have now:

```
Member Name  Letter Type
John Doe     Member 7 Day Letter
Jane Doe     Provider 7 Day Letter
Jane Doe     Member 7 Day Letter

ID    Letter Type
1001  Member 7 Day Letter
1002  Provider 7 Day Letter
```

How do I get the following output:

```
Member Name  Letter Sent
John Doe               1
Jane Doe               2
```

Comment: Did you check the documentation for [the `count()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions039.htm)? Particularly the optional `distinct` keyword?

Comment: @AdamSilenko - why do you think `Letter` and `Type` are separate columns, rather than `"Letter Type"` being another quoted identifier?

Comment: @AdamSilenko Please don't apply your own interpretation in edits. If you have a doubt clarify in comments. `"Letter Type"` was clearly one single column not separate columns in OPs original question.

Answer (score 0):

probably you need only count and group by:

```
SELECT "Member Name"
, "Letter Type"
, COUNT(1) AS n
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY "Member Name"
, "Letter Type";
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the output you want.

```
SELECT 
    "Member Name", 
    COUNT(DISTINCT "Letter Type") as "Letter Sent"
FROM <your-table>
GROUP BY "Member Name"
```

Also, I would advise you to go through the Oracle docs or follow some of the tutorials online, if you plan on using Oracle SQL more. These are really basic operations that should be covered by any decent tutorial.

Comment: Awesome!  This actually works.  I have added this piece to my sql code and the report ran smoothly.